# hotspot or wifi qr code genrate using zxing

Tags: android, html, android-studio, android-fragments, zxing

How can i generate a qr code for my hotspot(i have file which create hotspot with random ssid,password)
now I want to use zxing to create a qr code for it . with Authentication= wap/wap2. I also came across an api of this[site](https://qrcode.tec-it.com/en/WiFi) but its for html file     `<img src="https://qrcode.tec-it.com/API/QRCode?data=WIFI%3aT%3aWPA%3bS%3assid%3bP%3apaasword%3b%3b&backcolor=%23ffffff" />` if it is possible to get ssid and password from java file to this html file thats great and easy pls share an html code for it . Or we can use zxing pls help me to   modify this code to create a qr code with Authentication= wap/wap2. 
  Pls help I really need your valuable answer

```
package javaapplication27;
import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter;
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;
public class NewClass1{
        private static final String qcip = "C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\kamal\\qrcode.png";
  private static void generateQRCode(String text, int width, int height, String filePath)
            throws Exception {
        QRCodeWriter qcwobj = new QRCodeWriter();
        BitMatrix bmobj = qcwobj.encode(text, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height);
        Path pobj = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(filePath);
        MatrixToImageWriter.writeToPath(bmobj, "PNG", pobj);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            generateQRCode("My Name Is Kamalpreet singh",1250, 1250, qcip);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not generate QR Code" + e);
        } 

    }
```

Comment: [https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Barcode-Contents#wi-fi-network-config-android-ios-11] guys pls tell me how to use zxings wor generating wifi config qr code

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [Github](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Barcode-Contents#wi-fi-network-config-android-ios-11) page of the ZXing in order to create a WI-FI QR code so that other devices can read that code and automatically connect themselves to the WI-FI you need to encode a String with the following structure `WIFI:T:WPA;S:mynetwork;P:mypass;;` where:

- **T:WPA** is the authentication type which in this case is set to WPA;
- **S:mynetwork** is the network SSID which in this case is set to mynetwork;
- **P:mypass** is the network password which in this case is set to mypass;

As an example, lets say you want to generate a QR Code for the network with the following characteristics:

- **SSID**: My Home Network
- **Authentication Type**: WPA
- **Password**: ThisIsMyTopSecretPassword

For that, you could use the following code:

```java
import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.WriterException;
import com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter;
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public static void main( String[] args ) throws WriterException, IOException {
    QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
    BitMatrix bitMatrix = writer.encode("WIFI:T:WPA;S:My Home Network;P:ThisIsMyTopSecretPassword;;", BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 1920, 1080);

    Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:/Users/user/Desktop/image.png");
    MatrixToImageWriter.writeToPath(bitMatrix, "PNG", path);
}
```

This will generate the QR code with a width of 1920px and an height of 1080px for the previously mentioned network and store that QR code as an image with the PNG format in the Desktop of the user "user".

Even though it comes at a late time I hope it might still be of help to future readers.